# Как добавить перенос строки (не в string)?

Tags: javascript

Имеются две переменные с заданным значением.
Использую `alert`,  чтобы отобразить значения с описанием к ним:

```
alert ("описание1: " + myVariable1 + "описание2: " + myVariable2);
```

**Как добавить перенос строки**  в данном случае?
`/n`, насколько я понимаю, работает только внутри строки (`string`).

Comment: Ну так алерту же стока и передается и он даже переводы строки понимает. alert("aaa"+...+"\n"+...)

Comment: Спасибо, я как раз  подумал про "\n", но думал может есть другой принятый способ. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь вы также можете добавить символ новой строки:

```
alert ("описание1: " + myVariable1 + "\nописание2: " + myVariable2);
```

или

```
alert ("описание1: " + myVariable1 + "\n" + "описание2: " + myVariable2);
```

Вы как раз получаете одну строку внутри `alert`.

Comment: Да, это то что нужно, спасибо огромное!

Comment: @MaximVelichkin Да не за что.